# InteliJ doesn't create OpenAPI directory in target/generated-sources on build and deletes it if it's added by hand

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

While building project with mvn clean install using console or maven in InteliJ I have error telling mi that there are missing packages. The same project works and other machines no problem. the diffrence is that while building on the other machine the missing packages are generated as described in plugins in pom.xml. Missig files are:

- ApiUtil
- DefaultApi
- APIResponseDTO

Has anyone had a similar problem?

```
<plugin>
    <!--                Override chassis openapi-generator-maven-plugin configuration-->
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/My-connectorAPI.yaml
                </inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.MyApp.MyService.xmldownloader.api
                </apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>
                    ${project.groupId}.MyApp.MyService.xmldownloader.model
                </modelPackage>
                <configOptions>
    <wwq>23`R4</wwq>                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

XmlDownloaderAPIController.java is a Class that implements DefaultApi from openAPI.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project My-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyApp/My-service/src/main/java/pl/com/<...>/internal/XmlDownloaderAPIController.java:[15,87] package pl.com.<...>.xmldownloader.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyApp/My-service/src/main/java/pl/com/<...>/internal/XmlDownloaderAPIController.java:[22,89] package package pl.com.<...>.xmldownloader.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyApp/My-service/src/main/java/pl/com/<...>/internal/XmlDownloaderAPIController.java:[26,52] cannot find symbol
```

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project My-service: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I invalidated caches, made sure Java and maven version are the same, cloned project again, reinstalled InteliJ, made sure I have the same maven config files on both machines.

Comment: Fresh checkout without `.idea`. Run the appropriate maven target from the command line so all files are generated.  _Then_ open IntelliJ on the folder and let the auto detection finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the workaround! I deleted entire repository folder in C:\users\user\.m2, built service that provided nessesery dependency locally for my project and built my project successfully.